# dump man page on text file?

Tags: command-line, catalina, zsh

I'm trying to dump a man page to a text file, but for some reason I get error `No manual entry for (command)`

For example: `man strftime`  shows the man page ok, however, running

```
$ man strftime | col -b > strftime.txt 
No manual entry for strftime
```

Why is this?

Running Zsh on Catalina.

Comment: Works for me, in both bash and zsh.

Comment: PS: You can also run `groff -Tlatin1 -mandoc -c $(man -W strftime) > strftime.txt` to format a man page directly to text.

Comment: Try breaking down your command. You said `man strftime` works. So try `man strftime | col -b`. If that works, then add in the pipe to file. If that _doesn't work_ try to figure out what part is failing. Is it the `col`? Or the pipe to file?

Comment: @bryanH The error message comes from `man`, `col` doesn‘t even know what a manual entry is. I suspect a typo.

Comment: @nohillside Agreed, was helping OP learn how to simplify the problem down to the smallest condition.

Comment: Moving off-topic a little, you can show it as a PDF this way: `man -t strftime | open -f -a Preview`

Comment: Hey! Thanks @nohillside, BryanH at all, it wasn't a typo; I copied and pasted from the example I posted here and now it worked. Go figure! Thanks everyone for your input though!